# How to write a the content of variable to a text file (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to write the content of a StringVar to a text file in python. Basically I have a dropdown menu and a string variable called value_inside that is the value that the user picks in the dropdown menu. Once the code prints the value that the user picks, I want it to be able to write that value into a text file, but when I try `file=open("file.txt", "w") file.write(value_inside)`
I get an error that says "argument must be str, not StringVar". I think this means that I can't write string variable to a file. Do I need to convert it into something else? Or do I need to put a function that writes the actual value of the string variable into a file?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean a Tkinter StringVar? You should show some code, please...

Comment: ```.get()``` method needs to be invoked to get the contents of ```tk.StringVar()``` ```file.write(value_inside.get())```

Comment: Show minimum reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to invoke the `.get()` method to get the contents of `tk.StringVar()`

```
file=open("file.txt", "w") 
file.write(value_inside)
```